# Entering the second knowledge level of jenkins-scripted-pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

It is easy to find simple examples for declarative or scripted pipeline. But when the point comes where you go deep into scripting you need so much more information. When you're not familiar to the world of web, java and groovy you are running out of questions which can be asked to go future. Googeling helps you find some magic "hudson.model.Hudson..." or .methods and e.g. @NonCPS-operators solutions. Those solutions work, but I'm searching for the bigger context to work my self from the bottom up. Not from the top down. I'm looking for the knowledge, which is obvious to the insiders.

**I'm looking for links/books/api-references or introductions** to learn to find the entrance to knowledge around the jenkins scripted pipeline. e.g. like [this](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/master/README.md#technical-design) one =).

*I am not looking for answers to those questions below from the stackoverflow communety. This would be to much! I am looking for links of documentation to get deep into the topic. I assume that for an insider it's insider knowledge is not obvious. So I'm stating here some questions to make it obvious what I would describe as insider knowledge.*

#### Example questions:

- like : "hudson.model.Hudson..." but where do I get those magical dot.separated strings?
- Is there a documentation of the Jenkins Api?
- How can I find documentation of the classes and methods usable in jenkins like e.g. `X.Y.collect`?
- Is there a way to debug a pipeline?
- Is there a faster way in testing code than every time run it in a pipeline?
- How does the inner mechanism work?
- Is the Knowledge more about groovy or is it about general Jenkins? Or is it java?
- Why `println MyArrayList.getClass()` `class java.util.ArrayList` which is a java class? does grooy inherit the types from java, or does the pipeline inherit the types from jenkins, which is java?
- ...

Comment: I think this, as worded right now, is way too broad. There are too many questions here that have different levels of answerability - some asking for documentation, some for opinion, some that are too general. I voted to close as I believe this is too broad, and should be broken down into more specific questions or taken to one of  the Jenkins email lists.

Answer (score 1):

Asking one question at a time:

**where do I get those magical dot.separated strings?**
Those are inner java classes at the Jenkins core (or plugins). For the former, [Javadoc is available](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/Hudson), the latter have their code at [Github](https://github.com/jenkinsci)

**classes and methods usable in jenkins**
Mostly every Java and [Groovy](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/) class/method is usable

**debug a pipeline?**
You can only [replay it,](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/development/#replay) issuing changes on each Run

**testing**
you have two approaches: [LesFurets one](https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit) and the [real-unit-one](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/jenkins-global-shared-pipeline-libraries-real-unit-delgado-garrido/)

**innards**
wide question and wider answer. pipelines are [loaded, transformed and run](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin) as a near to groovy code (`@NonCPS` annotation alters this behaviour). 
Knowledge about Java, Groovy and Jenkins will apply.
Groovy indeed extends Java hence, both languages apply